# How to close modal window with this jquery function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Below is the Html button and javascript function I have which closes a modal window:

```
<button type="button" id="close" onclick="return parent.closewindow();">Close</button>

function closewindow() {     
    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
}
```

Now the code above does close the modal window which is fine.

But I want to know how to write the code by using this function and html button below:

```
<button type='button' class='add'>Add</button>



  $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){ 

        $.modal.close(); ;
        return true;
    });
```

The above code does not close the modal window, why is this? Both these codes are on the same page by the way.

I am using simplemodal developed by eric martin

UPDATE:

Below is full code (QandATable2.php) but it is still not closing modal window when clicking on "Add" button:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.add').on('click', function(){ 
//close modal window when user clicks on "Add" button (not working)
           $.modal.close();
      });
 });

function plusbutton() { 
    // Display an external page using an iframe 
    var src = "previousquestions.php"; 
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');

//Opens modal window and displays an iframe which contains content from another php script
    return false;
} 


function closewindow() {     

    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
//closes modal window when user clicks on "Close" button and this works fines
} 

...HTML

    <table id="plus" align="center">
    <tr>
    <th>
    <a onclick="return plusbutton();">
    <img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
    </a>
    <span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>
    </th>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Below is the full code which displays all of the information that goes into the modal window (this is in previousquestions.php script). This includes both "Add" and "Close" buttons:

```
<div id="previouslink">
<button type="button" id="close" onclick="return parent.closewindow();">Close</button>      
</div>

<?php 


      $output = "";

        while ($questionrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($questionresult)) {
$output .= "
<table>
      <tr>
      <td id='addtd'><button type='button' class='add'>Add</button></td>
      </tr>";
        }
        $output .= "        </table>";

        echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote the click function event handler code within a `$(document).ready() {` section?

Comment: `.on` works with event delegation, so it shouldn't be a problem even when executed before the DOM is ready (the only issue would be clicking in the button before the `modal` plugin is loaded, which would return an undefined function error in the console).

Comment: the modal window does open and the "add" button is stored in the modal window, but when I click on the "Add" button, then it doesn't close the modal window,

Comment: Try using `.live` instead of `.on` if you're using an older version of jQuery.

Comment: Tell us which `modal` plugin you're using and if you have any errors in the JS console.

Comment: I tried with document() function but still no difference. I edit code in question

Comment: I am using simplemodal developed by eric martin

Comment: I tried including document.ready() function by using the other answer but still no luck

Comment: @FabrícioMatté looks like the OP is using event delegation with the `.on` so it is doing the same as `.live` would.

Comment: @subhaze Exactly, that's why I suggested `.live` for older jQuery versions - `.on` is not supported in jQuery prior to 1.7

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I am using Jquery 1.7 so I can use .on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I remember from the comments, you wanted to close the modal when clicking in an `add` button inside the `modal` right?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.add').on('click', function(){ 
           $.modal.close();
      });
 });
```

​
I made your first example (before your question edit) work, take a look at this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/cS66y/)**.

Be careful with the order you show/hide elements and wrap your function inside the `$(document).ready()` to prevent the code execution before the DOM is loaded.

If you don't manage to adapt your page to work similarly to my fiddle, you should post more from your page's code as there'd probably be something causing the plugin to don't work properly (or switch to another modal plugin).

**edit:** You're using an `iframe`, that's why you can't access the parent window's defined functions from the `iframe`'s scope directly. You could try using the `window.opener` to access your parent window's scoped functions, or, to solve all and any window scope problem:

Replace

```
$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
```

With

```
$.modal('<div id="modal" style="border:0;width:100%;height:100%;">');
$('#modal').load(src);
```

This will load content to the div dynamically through Ajax, which is a better approach and resolves any window scope problems which you were facing.

Either that or switch to a modal plugin which supports loading pages directly to it, for instance, [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).

**EDIT**

Now with your full code it was easy to find a solution, simply add `onclick='parent.closewindow();'` to your `add` button in your PHP:

```
<td id='addtd'><button type='button' class='add' onclick='parent.closewindow();'>Add</button></td>
```

This way, it'll re-use the existing `closewindow` function and discard the `.on` binding for the `.add` buttons. :)

Comment: I have tried your code but it still hasn't worked. I have included an UPDATE in my question where it shows you whole code so you can see what it looks like and see if you can understand it by looking at whole code and hopefully be able to get the "Add" button to close the modal window

Comment: Oh, you're using an `iframe`, that's why you can't access the function which is defined in the parent window scope. Try `window.opener.$.modal.close();`. Not sure if you'd have to define the `.on` event inside the loaded iframe, I'll test.

Comment: Alright, I edited my answer swapping the iframe for a modal div with ajax, which should resolve any window scope problem. Give it a try. :) (remove the `window.opener` if you added it)

Comment: I gave it a try but the problem is that I need an iframe, without the iframe then it means that whenever I search for something within the modal window, then it will display the details on a sepearate page without the iframe whiile with the iframe it shows it within the modal window

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Try out calling the `window.opener` then, I'll test it to check the scopes.

Comment: Alright, I found an easier way around that. Check my new edit with the `onclick='parent.closewindow();'` solution.

Comment: I tried `$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.add').on('click', function(){ 
           window.opener.$.modal.close();
      });
 })` but still no luck

Comment: Yeah, F5 the page and try my new Edit. =]

Comment: The only reason I havn't used this method is that in the future i want the .add function to be able to append content into a textarea, so what my question is that would ` $('.add').on('click', function(){ ` never work? Or should I create a new onclick function which also closes a modal window but be able to do other features as well?

Comment: There's a scope restriction, there are 2 ways around that: With the `.on()` you'd have to call it inside the loaded page (which is more work), or the other option, copy and paste the current `closewindow` function and rename it, then call the new function from your `add`'s `onclick=parent.myNewFunc()` and edit the new function to append the text before closing the modal. Not sure if I explained it very well, I can make a quick example if you want.

Comment: No that's fine, I have already done it and it worked. Thank you for your help :)